# Manually deriving the type of `zipWith . uncurry`

Tags: haskell, types, ghci, unification

I'm trying to derive the type of `zipWith . uncurry`

`zipWith . uncurry = (.) zipWith uncurry` -- concatenation as function

```
(.) :: (b1 -> c1) -> (a1 -> b1) -> a1 -> c1
zipWith :: (a2 -> b2 -> c2) -> [a2] -> [b2] -> [c2]
uncurry :: (a3 -> b3 -> c3) -> (a3, b3) -> c3

b1 ~ (a2 -> b2 -> c2)
c1 ~ [a2] -> [b2] -> [c2]
a1 ~ (a3 -> b3 -> c3)
b1 ~ (a3, b3) -> c3
```

Replacing `a1` with `(a3 -> b3 -> c3)` and `c1` with `[a2] -> [b2] -> [c2]` I get:

```
(.) zipWith uncurry :: a1 -> c1 ~ (a3 -> b3 -> c3) -> [a2] -> [b2] -> [c2]
```

If I query GHCi for `:t zipWith . uncurry` I get: `(a -> b1 -> b -> c) -> [(a, b1)] -> [b] -> [c]`

I think the key is in `b1 ~ (a2 -> b2 -> c2) ~ (a3, b3) -> c3` but I don't realize how to match my result with the expected.

Any help?

Thanks,
Sebastián.

Comment: What would the benefit be of `uncurry` when  `zipWith` function works with two arguments. `zipWith (enumFromTo) [0,2..6] [1,3..7] ` yields **[[0,1],[2,3],[4,5],[6,7]]** or feeding it proper arguments as in `zipWith (:) [0,2..6] [[n]|n<-[1,3..7]]` yields the very same. The second argument of `(:)` must be a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we start with

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
zipWith :: (x -> y -> z) -> [x] -> [y] -> [z]
uncurry :: (u -> v -> w) -> (u, v) -> w
```

Then we match `zipWith`'s type with `(b -> c)` and `uncurry`'s type with `(a -> b)`:

```
b             -> c
(x -> y -> z) -> ([x] -> [y] -> [z])
```

And

```
a             -> b
(u -> v -> w) -> ((u, v) -> w)
```

Then we have to equate the `b` terms

```
b ~ x      -> (y -> z)
b ~ (u, v) -> w
```

So `w ~ (y -> z)` and `x ~ (u, v)`.  A table of what we've determined so far:

```
a ~ u -> v -> w
b ~ x -> y -> z
c ~ [x] -> [y] -> [z]
x ~ (u, v)
w ~ y -> z
```

So we can substitute `x` and `w` in:

```
a ~ u -> v -> (y -> z)
b ~ (u, v) -> y -> z
c -> [(u, v)] -> [y] -> [z]
```

And we can now complete the type of `zipWith . uncurry`:

```
(u -> v -> y -> z) -> ([(u, v)] -> [y] -> [z])
```

Which lines up with GHCi's answer as well.

The trick to these is just to line up the arrows and then just substitute back in until you can't reduce it any more.